# Absolute position inside column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page which consists of 3-column body. Inside the first and the third column there are buttons. I try to position them correctly.

In particular, I have a problem with the first column's button which must be displayed at the bottom of the page (near footer).

But the styles I used doesn't have an effect. I suppose it happens because the column is empty and positioning works relative to its height. I tried to make use of `height:100%;` property, but it didn't work.

How should I work around it?

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet"                                        href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
 html {
         position: relative;
         min-height: 100%;
      }
 body {
        margin-bottom: 20vh;
        background-color:#f2f2f2;
        }
       footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10vh; 
       }

        footer {
           background-color: black;
           color:white;
          }  </style>
         <style>
              #upButton {position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px;}
         </style>

         <style>
              .col1 {height:100%;}
         </style>
</head>
 <body>
             <div id="header" class="header" align="center">
                            <h1 align="center">Some header
                            <small>some subheader</smalll>
               </div>                         
           <div class="container">
                       <div class="row">
                                 <div  class="col-md-2 col1"> 
                                                  <a id="upButton" 
                                      href="#header" class="btn btn-success" 
                                      role="button">Up
                                                   </a>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-8">...</div>
                                 <div class="col-md-2">
                                     <a href="#f" align="right" class="btn 
                                 btn-danger" role="button">Down
                                     </a>
                                 </div>
                      </div>
          </div>  
     <footer>
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <p><a id="f">All right unreserved</a></p>
         </div>
      </footer>
</body>
```

So right now my solution works only if I put lots of text inside the first column - then the Up button is near footer, as it should be. But without text it goes upwards..

EDIT: I managed to solve it by putting both buttons right into body, but if there is a solution which allows for them to remain in their respective columns, I d like to know.[image: upbutton][image: downbutton]
  On the pictures the up button is next to the footer, while the down button is near header.

EDIT: The code with proposed solutions:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet"                                        href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
 html {
         position: relative;
         min-height: 100%;
      }
 body {
        margin-bottom: 20vh;
        background-color:#f2f2f2;
        }
       footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 10vh; 
       }

        footer {
           background-color: black;
           color:white;
          }  </style>


         <style>
                  #upButton {position:fixed; left:0px; bottom:100px;}
                  .col1 {height:100%;}
         </style>


</head>
 <body>
             <div id="header" class="header" align="center">
                            <h1 align="center">Some header
                            <small>some subheader</smalll>
               </div>                         
           <div class="container">
                       <div class="row">
                                 <div  class="col-md-2 col1"> 
                                                  <a id="upButton" 
                                      href="#header" class="btn btn-success" 
                                      role="button">Up
                                                   </a>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="col-md-8">.This book must have been revolutionary when it came out in the 1930s. The language, the style, the unbashed uncaring for literary norms must have been like a fresh air of rebellion to the stifled people of the 1930s who just few decades ago were under the moral oppression of the Victorian age. The book begins with an ode to Tanya's cunt. And it continues in the same manner. The word cunt is probably the most used word in the entire book. Today it would be called vulgar, but at the time it was revolutionary and brave. Miller describes multiple women he's had sex with while living in Paris, mostly on the money of other people, or as a vagrant and homeless on the streets. Most of the women he sleeps with are prostitutes (and he goes at length discussing the different types of prostitutes), but there is also the Jewish adulteress, the Russian princess with gonorrhea, the strange french woman to whom he gives 100 francs and then takes them out of her purse after having sex with her in her house above the room of her sick mother. Chapters of lucid description of characters (mostly Miller's friends whose money he uses, at whose houses he sleeps and whose women he has sex with) and some semblance of story lines are alternated with chapters of stream-of-consciousness monologues with prophetic statements and deep insights into life and living that usually come only after a very heavy intoxication with various substances. The book finishes in a middle of an action, just like it starts. Nothing really happens throughout and there's no sustained plot or even any novel-long characters (except the author-narrator) but it does give an entertaining and fascinating view into the life of the American emigres to Paris between the two wars in a much different way than Hemingway. POSTED BY MR.B. AT 2:12 PM NO COMMENTS: THURSDAY, JULY 7, 2016 "Mount Analogue" by Rene Daumal It ends in mid-sentence in the fifth chapter. Rene Daumal died days later of tubercolosis. He was in his 36th year of his life. Peradams. Only Father Sogol (Logos, took me a while to figure it out without anyone pointing it out to me) found one and very low, below the mountain where no Peradams are usually found, but he had an epiphany about himself. The book has an extensive intro section where the future planned chapters by Daumal are explained and it is a real shame that they were not written. Or maybe the book is more effective this way? After all Gurdjieff's "Life is real only when I AM" also stops in a middle of a sentence, and some who have seen the original manuscripts say that the published version is a much smaller selection from what was available. "Mount Analogue" is a very readable and well written book, to be expected from a writer of Daumal's caliber, and although Gurdjieff's name is never explicitly mentioned - it is based on the ideas and understanding of Gurdjieff's system (not to be called "The Fourth Way", but simply the "Gurdjieff System") and contains the personal thoughts and development of a person working on themselves according to the system. The explanation on how Mount Analogue This book must have been revolutionary when it came out in the 1930s. The language, the style, the unbashed uncaring for literary norms must have been like a fresh air of rebellion to the stifled people of the 1930s who just few decades ago were under the moral oppression of the Victorian age. The book begins with an ode to Tanya's cunt. And it continues in the same manner. The word cunt is probably the most used word in the entire book. Today it would be called vulgar, but at the time it was revolutionary and brave. Miller describes multiple women he's had sex with while living in Paris, mostly on the money of other people, or as a vagrant and homeless on the streets. Most of the women he sleeps with are prostitutes (and he goes at length discussing the different types of prostitutes), but there is also the Jewish adulteress, the Russian princess with gonorrhea, the strange french woman to whom he gives 100 francs and then takes them out of her purse after having sex with her in her house above the room of her sick mother. Chapters of lucid description of characters (mostly Miller's friends whose money he uses, at whose houses he sleeps and whose women he has sex with) and some semblance of story lines are alternated with chapters of stream-of-consciousness monologues with prophetic statements and deep insights into life and living that usually come only after a very heavy intoxication with various substances. The book finishes in a middle of an action, just like it starts. Nothing really happens throughout and there's no sustained plot or even any novel-long characters (except the author-narrator) but it does give an entertaining and fascinating view into the life of the American emigres to Paris between the two wars in a much different way than Hemingway. POSTED BY MR.B. AT 2:12 PM NO COMMENTS: THURSDAY, JULY 7, 2016 "Mount Analogue" by Rene Daumal It ends in mid-sentence in the fifth chapter. Rene Daumal died days later of tubercolosis. He was in his 36th year of his life. Peradams. Only Father Sogol (Logos, took me a while to figure it out without anyone pointing it out to me) found one and very low, below the mountain where no Peradams are usually found, but he had an epiphany about himself. The book has an extensive intro section where the future planned chapters by Daumal are explained and it is a real shame that they were not written. Or maybe the book is more effective this way? After all Gurdjieff's "Life is real only when I AM" also stops in a middle of a sentence, and some who have seen the original manuscripts say that the published version is a much smaller selection from what was available. "Mount Analogue" is a very readable and well written book, to be expected from a writer of Daumal's caliber, and although Gurdjieff's name is never explicitly mentioned - it is based on the ideas and understanding of Gurdjieff's system (not to be called "The Fourth Way", but simply the "Gurdjieff System") and contains the personal thoughts and development of a person working on themselves according to the system. The explanation on how Mount Analogue would have been physically hidden from anyone for so long is definitely done by the latest science available at that period (1930s), but with today's satellites and space observation does not hold well at all, although it was probably ingenious for the time. Also getting there, getting in and discovering no new technology (based on electricity) works on the mountain is also very interesting, especially connected to Gurdjieff's notion that electricity was discovered before and is not an inexhaustible resource. Of course, Father Sogol is no one but Alexandre de (von) Saltzmann, one of the foremost Gurdjieff's students, of whom not as much is known, compared to the other students like Alexandre's wife Jeanne, and the de (von) Hartmann's. He must have been a formidable personality to have left such an impression on Daumal. This book is a gem, even in its unfinished form, or maybe because of it.This book must have been revolutionary when it came out in the 1930s. The language, the style, the unbashed uncaring for literary norms must have been like a fresh air of rebellion to the stifled people of the 1930s who just few decades ago were under the moral oppression of the Victorian age. The book begins with an ode to Tanya's cunt. And it continues in the same manner. The word cunt is probably the most used word in the entire book. Today it would be called vulgar, but at the time it was revolutionary and brave. Miller describes multiple women he's had sex with while living in Paris, mostly on the money of other people, or as a vagrant and homeless on the streets. Most of the women he sleeps with are prostitutes (and he goes at length discussing the different types of prostitutes), but there is also the Jewish adulteress, the Russian princess with gonorrhea, the strange french woman to whom he gives 100 francs and then takes them out of her purse after having sex with her in her house above the room of her sick mother. Chapters of lucid description of characters (mostly Miller's friends whose money he uses, at whose houses he sleeps and whose women he has sex with) and some semblance of story lines are alternated with chapters of stream-of-consciousness monologues with prophetic statements and deep insights into life and living that usually come only after a very heavy intoxication with various substances. The book finishes in a middle of an action, just like it starts. Nothing really happens throughout and there's no sustained plot or even any novel-long characters (except the author-narrator) but it does give an entertaining and fascinating view into the life of the American emigres to Paris between the two wars in a much different way than Hemingway. POSTED BY MR.B. AT 2:12 PM NO COMMENTS: THURSDAY, JULY 7, 2016 "Mount Analogue" by Rene Daumal It ends in mid-sentence in the fifth chapter. Rene Daumal died days later of tubercolosis. He was in his 36th year of his life. Peradams. Only Father Sogol (Logos, took me a while to figure it out without anyone pointing it out to me) found one and very low, below the mountain where no Peradams are usually found, but he had an epiphany about himself. The book has an extensive intro section where the future planned chapters by Daumal are explained and it is a real shame that they were not written. Or maybe the book is more effective this way? After all Gurdjieff's "Life is real only when I AM" also stops in a middle of a sentence, and some who have seen the original manuscripts say that the published version is a much smaller selection from what was available. "Mount Analogue" is a very readable and well written book, to be expected from a writer of Daumal's caliber, and although Gurdjieff's name is never explicitly mentioned - it is based on the ideas and understanding of Gurdjieff's system (not to be called "The Fourth Way", but simply the "Gurdjieff System") and contains the personal thoughts and development of a person working on themselves according to the system. The explanation on how Mount Analogue would have been physically hidden from anyone for so long is definitely done by the latest science available at that period (1930s), but with today's satellites and space observation does not hold well at all, although it was probably ingenious for the time. Also getting there, getting in and discovering no new technology (based on electricity) works on the mountain is also very interesting, especially connected to Gurdjieff's notion that electricity was discovered before and is not an inexhaustible resource. Of course, Father Sogol is no one but Alexandre de (von) Saltzmann, one of the foremost Gurdjieff's students, of whom not as much is known, compared to the other students like Alexandre's wife Jeanne, and the de (von) Hartmann's. He must have been a formidable personality to have left such an impression on Daumal. This book is a gem, even in its unfinished form, or maybe because of it.This book must have been revolutionary when it came out in the 1930s. The language, the style, the unbashed uncaring for literary norms must have been like a fresh air of rebellion to the stifled people of the 1930s who just few decades ago were under the moral oppression of the Victorian age. The book begins with an ode to Tanya's cunt. And it continues in the same manner. The word cunt is probably the most used word in the entire book. Today it would be called vulgar, but at the time it was revolutionary and brave. Miller describes multiple women he's had sex with while living in Paris, mostly on the money of other people, or as a vagrant and homeless on the streets. Most of the women he sleeps with are prostitutes (and he goes at length discussing the different types of prostitutes), but there is also the Jewish adulteress, the Russian princess with gonorrhea, the strange french woman to whom he gives 100 francs and then takes them out of her purse after having sex with her in her house above the room of her sick mother. Chapters of lucid description of characters (mostly Miller's friends whose money he uses, at whose houses he sleeps and whose women he has sex with) and some semblance of story lines are alternated with chapters of stream-of-consciousness monologues with prophetic statements and deep insights into life and living that usually come only after a very heavy intoxication with various substances. The book finishes in a middle of an action, just like it starts. Nothing really happens throughout and there's no sustained plot or even any novel-long characters (except the author-narrator) but it does give an entertaining and fascinating view into the life of the American emigres to Paris between the two wars in a much different way than Hemingway. POSTED BY MR.B. AT 2:12 PM NO COMMENTS: THURSDAY, JULY 7, 2016 "Mount Analogue" by Rene Daumal It ends in mid-sentence in the fifth chapter. Rene Daumal died days later of tubercolosis. He was in his 36th year of his life. Peradams. Only Father Sogol (Logos, took me a while to figure it out without anyone pointing it out to me) found one and very low, below the mountain where no Peradams are usually found, but he had an epiphany about himself. The book has an extensive intro section where the future planned chapters by Daumal are explained and it is a real shame that they were not written. Or maybe the book is more effective this way? After all Gurdjieff's "Life is real only when I AM" also stops in a middle of a sentence, and some who have seen the original manuscripts say that the published version is a much smaller selection from what was available. "Mount Analogue" is a very readable and well written book, to be expected from a writer of Daumal's caliber, and although Gurdjieff's name is never explicitly mentioned - it is based on the ideas and understanding of Gurdjieff's system (not to be called "The Fourth Way", but simply the "Gurdjieff System") and contains the personal thoughts and development of a person working on themselves according to the system. The explanation on how Mount Analogue would have been physically hidden from anyone for so long is definitely done by the latest science available at that period (1930s), but ..</div>
                                 <div class="col-md-2">
                                     <a href="#f" align="right" class="btn 
                                 btn-danger" role="button">Down
                                     </a>
                                 </div>
                      </div>
          </div>  
     <footer>
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <p><a id="f">All right unreserved</a></p>
         </div>
      </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a desired look of you're trying to do with this? An image would be appreciated.

Comment: See my answer... I think you are making a navigation button to go up to your page, my solution is stacked at the bottom of your view port so if you want some margin, please add margin-bottom: {height of your footer}px;...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your style to this. The output maybe the result your looking for.

```
<style>
  #upButton {position:fixed; left:0px; bottom:0px;}
  .col1 {height:100%;}
</style>
```

I changed the position from absolute to fixed, try to read different values for position... [CSS Layout - The position Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Comment: Thanks, that works almost as expected. But is it possible to make the "up" button to stick to the bottom, so that when I can't see the footer, I can't see the button too?

Comment: hm... Could pass the whole code of your page? So I can could try to fix it?

Comment: Sure. Edited the post, see the last code block. Try to use this site http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_default, it displayes the code correctly.

Answer (score 2):

One method I would recommend is that you use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

First make sure `body`, `container`, `row` and `col1` all take up full height even when empty (inspect to confirm).

If they do, then set `col1` to `display:flex`. You could easily then use the `flex-end` property of flex children to make it stay down.

```
#upButton {
 align-self: flex-end
}
```

Comment: I'd go with this, flex box is a good choice and the support is pretty wide: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

Making the **upButton** fixed we can control it irrespective of it's parent So this way we can achieve your requirement

```
  <head>
     <style>
           #upButton {position:fixed; left:5px; bottom:5px;}
           .col1 { height:100%; }
     </style> 
  </head>
  <body>

       <div class="container-fluid">
                   <div class="row" style="height: 100%">
                             <div class="col-xs-2 col1"> 
                                <a id="upButton" href="#header" class="btn btn-success" role="button">Up
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-xs-8">.......</div>
                             <div class="col-xs-2">
                                 <a href="#f" align="right" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Down
                                 </a>
                             </div>
                  </div>
          </div>  

</body>
```

Live demo : https://jsbin.com/kuberop/2/edit?html,output